# Report Server web service is not marked up

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have installed SSRS 2019. I can browse to the local web portal URL which is http://av/Reports/browse/
and get the usual message of:

> You are not allowed to view this folder. Contact your administrator to
> obtain the necessary permissions.

So then I load up another browser as administrator and try get to the web service URL to give myself permission :
http://localhost/reportserver

but I just keep getting a page with no markup. See the image. What else am I missing here? Im not getting any error but also I am unable to administer the report server.

[image]